# French letter closings in English?

Tags: english, french

When I first learned about [the Closing Formula for French business letters](http://french.about.com/library/weekly/aa052501.htm), I had found them affected and foreign, especially since I haven't seen them in modern English (though [I'm unversed in complex writing like philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/21681)). To my surprise, while seeking letters to read on Founders Online [to improve my reading comprehension](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42834/8712), I encountered this formula in English, though from the late 1700s to early 1800s.

1. What are some formal terms describing this issue?

2. Please explain its usage in English vs French? Why did it ebb in English?

> [A search for `you to believe the`](http://founders.archives.gov/index.xqy?q=%22you+to+believe+the+%22&s=1111211111&sa=&r=1&sr=) effects [this letter dated 1804 May 11](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=%22you%20to%20believe%20the%20%22&s=1111311111&sa=&r=3&sr=):
>   I beg you to believe the Assurances of ...   
>   [ = Je vous prie de croire l'assurance de ...]
>
> [A search for `you to accept the`](http://founders.archives.gov/index.xqy?q=%22you+to+accept+the+%22&s=1111211111&sa=&r=1&sr=) effects 234 results of the form:
>   ... beg/entreat/pray you to accept ...  [ = ... vous {la conjugasion de « prier »} d'agréer/accepter ... ...]

Comment: I suggest you read Boswell's "Life of Samuel Johnson", which contains lots of letters that will give you a good feel for the letter-writing conventions in the late 18th century (and also give you some good models for elegant English prose). May I add that the common usage of the phrase "French letters" gives the title of your question a perhaps unintended comical twist.

Comment: @fdb Thank you for your helpful comment! I shall try it. Please feel free to add to or edit my post any time; you fronted your last sentence with 'May I add that' which suggests a polite hesitation? About 'French letters', were you referring to http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=french+letter' ? I had never before known about this ribald meaning.